# How should I match the impedance?

Tags: plc, io

I have a problem for getting the 4-20mA input via 1769-IF8 I/O module. My field device is in good condition, but my AI card doesn’t respond. When I have been browsing about it, most of them said, the impedance of the field device and AI module are not matched.

I don’t have any idea about how to match the impedance of both,explain to me how should match the impedance successfully?

Comment: You **DO NOT** match a 4/20 mA signal impedance with a load impedance.

Comment: Do you have a power supply for the sensor? Many current loop sensors require an external power source. See the wiring diagram in the manual. If you draw a diagram it will help people answer better.

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the input to match the 4-20mA transmitter output.

See the [manual](https://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/in/1769-in067_-en-p.pdf)

[image]

A 4~20mA output has very high output resistance (or it would not be a constant current source) and the properly configured input will have a resistance of something like 250\$\Omega\$ so the impedances are not matched, however the input configuration should correspond to the source.

Comment: OK, Thank you for reply I'll consider it.